# Dropbox sync API does not returns file with no extension

Tags: android, linux, dropbox

I was working with dropbox sync api on android platform, all seems to work smoothly except following case:
When i upload a file on dropbox which has no extension, then a call to `listFolder(dbxPath)` does not return file that had `no extension`.

I am uploading file through `Linux platform`, e.g A filename `XYZ` which is text file on linux.
but when i changing the filename of the same file to `XYZ.txt`, then, `listFolder(dbxPath)` returns the info about file.

It would be nice if someone explain this behavior, and possible solution too (as dropbox application is able to show `XYZ` file).

Comment: What permissions does your app have? Is it possible it uses the "file type" permission and simply doesn't have permission to read extensionless files?

Comment: I am using access to `documents` permission

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense then. The documents file type doesn't include extensionless files. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving this to an answer... the issue is that you have "documents" permission, and that doesn't include extensionless files.

See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/devguide#app-permissions for the full list of file extensions supported by each file type.

Comment: I should have read the documentation, thank you for pointing out. Dropbox Api rocks.